# Torrent uploading on a college network

Tags: bittorrent

For a very good reason my college uses a method for throttling torrent traffic that means that people can't connect to you when you are downloading torrents so my upload rate is always 0 (even when I can download a torrent). This means I can't download a torrents that don't allow leaching without seeding and downloading a torrent without uploading anything is kind of a crappy thing to do. Any recommendations on how to get around this barrier would be appreciated (and don't feel bad! I limit my torrent traffic anyway so I wouldn't screw the network with my new power).

Comment: They limit this stuff for a reason, and the traffic is very obviously what it is, even when encrypted. Can you really not find a free/cheap alternative to whatever you're downloading?

Comment: The limit on the university is, I hope, based on the fact that torrent takes up a lot of traffic - even with limitations. So you shouldn't really try going around the limit, even for legitimate traffic, unless there's something that makes your case somehow special. Don't try to hog the wire(less). :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get a [**Seedbox**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seedbox) and be done with it.

Answer (score 5):

Get a cheap Server like [kimsufi](http://www.kimsufi.com/) for example, and tunnel your torrents. Or superseed them with rtorrent directly from the webserver.

The best way to do it is to use [rtorrent](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTorrent) in command line, it's not as easy as utorrent, but, you can get used to it. Follow some [cheatsheet](http://tekguru.files.wordpress.com/2009/05/rtorrent_ref.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

Use a proxy or a private VPN to hide your activity from the school. See Hotspot Shield or HTTP-Tunnel Client.